# Find mail rules that are no longer being used

Tags: macos, mail.app, mail-rules

I have over 80 rules in Mail, many are for automatically filing mail from service providers to folders. Some of these are probably obsolete, as they were for temporary situations, or refer to providers that my company no longer uses or havee changed the address they send from, and I'd like to clean them up. Is there any way to find out which rules have been used recently and which ones haven't?

If I suspect a rule is no longer needed I can mark it as inactive, then see if any unwanted mail shows up in my regular inbox. But with so many rules, that's a cumbersome process.